# Python, theano Runtimeerror: could not initialize elemwise support

Tags: python, opencl, theano, gpu

Sorry if this happens to be trivial as I happen to be new with these stuff. I setup theano to use my gpu for computations on ubuntu trusty tahr. I have AMD Radeon HD 7670M gpu. When I try to run the test script to check the functioning of the theano with gpu, I get the following error:

```
Mapped name None to device opencl0:0: Turks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    f = function([], T.exp(x))
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/compile/function.py", line 322, in function
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 480, in pfunc
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1784, in orig_function
    defaults)
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1648, in create
    input_storage=input_storage_lists, storage_map=storage_map)
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/gof/link.py", line 699, in make_thunk
    storage_map=storage_map)[:3]
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/gof/vm.py", line 1042, in make_all
    no_recycling))
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/gof/op.py", line 975, in make_thunk
    no_recycling)
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/gof/op.py", line 875, in make_c_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1189, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1130, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/sachu/git/Theano/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1602, in cthunk_factory
    *(in_storage + out_storage + orphd))
RuntimeError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<GpuArrayType<None>(float64, (False,))>), '\n', 'Could not initialize elemwise support')
```

The script I ran was the one available on the website: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html
Is it something wrong with the config? I believe all dependencies are set properly, but I could have made some mistake, but then I would probably something other than runtime-error. I searched a lot on the github for info related to this, but found nothing. Same was the result after searching on stackoverflow, heance I am posting this here. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Additional Info: python3.4, theano bleeding edge version. Libgpuarray, clblas, openblas are all built from the git source master branch. 64bit architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Theano support for OpenCL is just not ready yet and it does not seem to be a priority for the development team to get this working (see [this issue](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5418)). So either you will need some patience or an nvidia GPU on which you could run CUDA.